# Does azure blob storage support http2?

Tags: linux, azure, azure-storage, http2

When I run:

```
curl -I --http2 https://MYACCOUNT.blob.core.cloudapi.de/MYCONTAINER/MYPATH
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Does this mean azure blob storage doesn't support http2 at all?

Comment: Not yet, however you can add a CDN on top and get HTTP/2 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-for-all-azure-cdn-customers/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Currently, Azure blob does not support http2. You could check this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6510044-support-http-2-and-spdy).

But now Azure CDN supports http/2 currently, see this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-for-all-customers-with-azure-cdn-from-akamai/).